# Why is #import Foundation.h widespread in Objective-C but individual imports are typical in Java

Tags: java, objective-c, import, header-files

From what I've seen, Android development requires the traditional Java style importing of each individual class/interface while the suggested templates in XCode import files like Foundation and UIKit. What is the difference in the compiler between Obj-C and Java that makes this sort of big import OK in one, but not OK in the other?

To be clear, I am not whining that this is not available in Java, I am just curious why it would be bad to do something like importing `java.util.*` or creating some sort of super header file that imports a lot of stuff.

Comment: Objective-C and Java are entirely different languages with different histories and differenct concepts (in language design, compiler implementation and "runtime philosophy" if you want to call it that). It *shouldn't* be a suprise that some aspects of developing in those languages differe between each other.

Comment: Not a surprise, but I am just curious why this is the case. For example, if I created some sort of super header file in Java with lots of import directives, how would that differ from Foundation.h?

Comment: There *are no header files* in Java. So the concept simply doesn't apply. The equivalent to the information stored in header files can be read from the `.class` files in Java, so `.h` files (or their equivalent) are not required in Java.

Comment: In Java there's no need to import individual classes one by one. You can use wildcards to import an entire package. The `import java.util.*;` sentence is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to note is that the only *source code* you need to compile any given Java class is the source code of that class.

Everything else needs to be available in compiled form only (i.e. as `.class` files). This means that a single `.java` file is always a syntacitcally closed unit that needs no other *source code* to make interpretable to a compiler.

This is quite different to how C-style languages treat external dependencies: they need type and function definitions (as well as macros and some things I probably forgot about right now) in order to be able to correctly parse and compile a  `.c` file (of course *some* `.c` files might be syntactically closed, but that's not the usual case).

The closest you can get to including a huge `.h` file in Java is using a `.*` import to import all classes of a given package: `import foo.bar.*`, but that's still miles away from the C/C++/Objective-C way.

And on a separate note: `import foo.*` is probably a bit less common in Java than individual imports for a simple reason: Individual imports are much more explicit and make it very clear which classes are used *and* they are usually written by your IDE of choice anyway, so this choice doesn't even make Java code harder to write.